# SVM Classifier ValueError: Found input variables with inconsistent shapes

Tags: python, arrays, dataframe, classification, svm

I'm currently working on a project where I have a CSV file with two columns, "features" and "labels." The "features" column contains arrays (vectors) with varying lengths, and the "labels" column has two classes, "Controlled" and "Abnormal."

I'm trying to apply an SVM classifier to this data, but I keep encountering a Value Error: Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of samples: [1, 800]

```
label_encoder = LabelEncoder()
y = label_encoder.fit_transform(y)

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.2, random_state=42)

svm_classifier = SVC(kernel='rbf', C=1.0) #error-here
svm_classifier.fit(X_train, y_train)
y_pred = svm_classifier.predict(X_test)
```

Output:
Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of samples: [1, 800]

[image]

Comment: You did not show how you are generating X in this case. Also, X needs to have the same number of columns, so it would not be possible to train a model given that there might be a different amount of columns in some rows.